# Can entanglements themselves be entangled?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

In other words, could there be higher dimensional entanglements between entanglements? For instance, this could allow us to entangle two entangled-far-away pairs to create a system of four entangled particles.

I am sorry if this sounds like a silly question.

Comment: See Entanglement swapping in the litterature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entanglement is a property, so it doesn't make sense to "entangle entanglements". However you *can* entangle entangled objects. And indeed, if you have two entangled pairs, you can create four-particle entanglement that way. For example, you could create a four-particle cluster state (cluster states are special entangled states useful for quantum computing) by taking two Bell pairs, and do an entangling operation between one of the particles of each pair.

Note however that you still need to bring those particles together. You don't need to bring *all* the particles together, however; in my example above, the second electron of the two Bell pairs could be both far away, and yet they'd still be part of the four-particle entangled state.

You can even "measure out" the entanglement from the two particles you did the entanglement operations on, and end up with the two other particles forming an entangled Bell pair despite them never having been close to each other. That basically is what happens in entanglement swapping (except that instead of first entangling and then "measuring out" you do an entangling measurement, but as far as the remote particles are concerned, that's equivalent).

However note that you *cannot* use that to entangle previously unentangled particles. While in the entanglement swapping case, the two particles that get entangled need never have come close to each other, they both already have been entangled with another particle each, and those "entanglement partners" indeed *did* come close to each other.

Especially if you have two entangled pairs which are in different places, there's no way to entangle them without either getting at least one of the particles of each pair together, or using a third entangled system where one pair directly interacts with one part of that third system, and the other pair directly interacts with the other part.

So entanglement can only be created locally, but it can be "redistributed" along existing "entanglement connections".

Comment: Interesting. So entanglement is basically a transitive, reflexive and symmetric relationship (i.e. an equivalence class) on the set of all particles. 

Moreover, you say that this relation is not physically encoded anywhere and therefore we can not play around with the relations themselves. I just find this incredibly hard to believe. It seems like all this information has to be stored somewhere. Otherwise, how does nature remember what is entangled, what is not? 

I am an outsider to physics. Do you know of any candidate foundational theories that take relations more "seriously" so to speak?

Comment: No, entanglement is not an equivalence relation. "Entanglement" means loosly speaking, "correlation between systems". As such, it is neither reflexive (a particle cannot be entangled with itself by definition), nor transitive (it can happen, that several particles are entangled, yet if you ignore some particles, the resulting pair is not entangled).

Comment: You can simply define a particle to be entangled with itself, it does no harm right? Moreover, if A~B and B~C, then we have A~C. (This is why the entanglement swapping works?) I don't understand what you mean when you say "ignore some particles". Why does that represent a violation of transitivity?

Comment: Most importantly, entanglement is not a relation in the mathematical sense because in general, particles can be entangled in inequivalent ways. That is, there is not only "entangled" and "not entangled", there are different inequivalent *ways* in which particles can be entangled. Systems consisting of just two systems which have just two states each (that is, two qubits) are special in that regard, since they are the only system that shows only one type of entanglement. Indeed, in the case of more than two particles, there's even no longer an unique maximally entangled state.